# Formulario de inserción de datos PHP Y MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Buenas noches realizo un formulario en el cual contiene checkbox pero al presionar el botón guardar me arroja el siguiente error.

> Notice: Undefined variable: mysql in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicio\curso\guardar.php on line 30
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicio\curso\guardar.php on line 30

```html
<?php
 
 require 'conexion.php';
 
 $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
 $estado_civil = $_POST['estado_civil'];
 $hijos = isset($_POST['hijo']) ? $_POST['hijos'] : 0;
 $intereses = isset($_POST['intereses']) ? $_POST['intereses'] : null;
 
 $arrayIntereses = null;
 
 $num_array = count($intereses);
 $contador = 0;
 
 if($num_array>0){
  foreach ($intereses as $key => $value) {
   if ($contador != $num_array-1)
   {
    $arrayIntereses .= $value.' ';
    $contador++;
    } else {
    $arrayIntereses .= $value;
   }
  }
 }
 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO personas (nombre, correo, telefono, estado_civil, hijos, intereses) VALUES ('$nombre', '$email', '$telefono', '$estado_civil', '$hijos', '$arrayIntereses')";
 $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
 
?>

<html lang="es">
 <head>
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
     <?php if($resultado) { ?>
      <h3>REGISTRO GUARDADO</h3>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <h3>ERROR AL GUARDAR</h3>
     <?php } ?>
     
     <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-primary">Regresar</a>
     
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tu linea 30 es esta? $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql); si es asi, fijate que la variable de conexion se llame $mysqli

Comment: Por cierto, tu codigo es sensible a inyeccion sql, seria bueno que utilices sentencia preparadas!

Comment: Hola Alejo Mendoza, en mi conexion si utilizo mysql y de echo cambie la conexion por otra con mysqli y marca el mismo error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:)

Asegurate que la variable `$mysqli` la hayas definido antes en el archivo de la conexión. 
Como lo indica en el error al intentar executar la funcion `query()` falla pues el valor de `$mysqli` es nulo.
Tu variable debe estar definida así:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("Hosting", "tu_usuario", "tu_contraseña", "basededatos");
```

De lo controrario, podrías intentarlo de la manera procedural, ya que parece que lo estás combinando con Orientada a Objetos:

**(Archivo De Conexión)**

```
$hostnombre = "localhost";
$dbusuario = "usuario";
$dbnombre = "NombreBaseDedatos";
$dbcontraseña = "contraseña";

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($hostnombre, $dbusuario, $dbcontraseña, $dbnombre);
```

.
.
.
.

**Obteniendo el resultado**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO personas (nombre, correo, telefono, estado_civil, hijos, intereses) VALUES ('$nombre', '$email', '$telefono', '$estado_civil', '$hijos', '$arrayIntereses')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)
```

Espero que sea de tu ayuda.